# How do I find the difference in levels between two vectors of ordered factors in R?

Tags: r, ordinal

Let's say I have two ordered factors `start` and `end` that are the same length and use the same levels. How do I return a vector that shows me how many levels each element has changed from `start` to `end`?

So for example let's say we have:

```
start = 'C5',  NA,   'C3',   'C5',   'T1'
end =   'C5', 'C5',   NA  ,  'C6',   'C6'
Levels: C2 < C3 < C4 < C5 < C6 < C7 < C8 < T1 < T2 < T3 < T4 < T5 < T6 < T7 < T8 < T9 < T10 < T11 < T12 < S1 < S2 < S3 < S45
```

what I ideally want is for something simple like `end - start` to give me `c(0, NA, NA, 1, -3)`

Here's code setting up the above example

```
lvls<-c("C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8",
        "T1","T2","T3","T4","T5","T6","T7","T8","T9","T10","T11","T12",
        "S1","S2","S3","S45")
start<-c('C5',  NA,   'C3',   'C5',   'T1') 
start<-ordered(start,levels=lvls)

end<-c('C5', 'C5',   NA  , 'C6',   'C6')
end<-ordered(end,levels=lvls)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found what I would think is an unnecesarrily complicated way of doing it. I'll gladly accept a simpler more elegant answer.

```
> start_lvls<-sapply(start,function(elem){match(TRUE,c(elem==levels(elem)))})
> end_lvls<-sapply(end,function(elem){match(TRUE,c(elem==levels(elem)))})
> end_lvls-start_lvls
[1]  0 NA NA  1 -3
```

And since I have hundreds of ordered factors and because I want to be able to analyse the difference between any two of them I now use these to make my life easier:

```
# Returns a vector that is the numeric value of what level each ordered factor in orderedFactorVec is
numericLevels<-function(orderedFactorVec){
  return(sapply(orderedFactorVec,function(elem){match(TRUE,c(elem==levels(elem)))}))
}

# Returns a vector that is the numeric difference between the two given ordered factor vectors (i.e end - start)
levelsChange<-function(start,end){
 return(numericLevels(end)-numericLevels(start)) 
}
```

Comment: `match` is vectorized, so `match(end, unique(lvls)) - match(start, unique(lvls))`.